# UNIX shell script - removing unwanted operator using expr

Tags: shell, unix

I've encountered a problem. I was writing a simple calculator using expr (it's a task) and I couldn't solve how to get warning when my operator is something different then + - / *.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
   echo arg op arg ...
   exit 1
fi

ans=0
operator='+'

while [ "$1" ]
do

if [ "$1" != '+' ] ; then
if [ "$1" != '-' ] ; then
if [ "$1" != '/' ] ; then
if [ "$1" != '*' ] ; then

if [ "$1" = "0" ];
    then
        echo "You can't divide by 0"
        exit
    fi;

ans=$(expr $ans "$operator" $1 2>/dev/null)

if [ "$?" = "2" ]
    then
     echo "Only integers"
     exit
    fi;

fi; fi; fi; fi;
operator=$1

shift
done

echo "Answer: $ans";
```

Also, maybe there is any way to write down those 4 conditions in one line. My attempt at solving it was something like:

```
if [ [ "$1" = '+' || "$1" = '-' || "$1" = '*' || "$1" = '/' ] ] then
echo "Wrong operator"
fi
```

after 4 condtions with + - / *

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statment:

```
case $1 in
'+') : handle + ;;
'-') : handle - ;;
'*') : handle *;;
'/') : handle /;;
*) echo Unrecognized operator: $1 >&2;;
esac
```

Comment: After replacing my 4 condtions with your code it doesn't work. There is an error even with addition. `./kalx.sh 4 + 1 Unrecognized operator: 4 Only integers`

Comment: Given that you emit the warning re: division by zero if the user were to enter `0 + 4`, I'm sure there are other changes that need to be made.

Comment: But it works in my code. When typing `4 + 1` it will give `5`, `4 + 1.5` will give `only integeres`, `4 / 0` will give `you can't divide by 0`. I just need this one condition that would not accept for example `4 . 2`, something like: if operator != + || - || * || / then echo "wrong operator". There must be an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment on my other answer, but it's too hard to format in a comment.  The following edits to your script show what I have in mind, but this script is still horribly broken.  (As I mentioned above, it behaves incorrectly on input "0 + 4".)  Also, adding the check on the operator exposes the lack of a 'shift' and the attempt to use the first operand as an operator:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
   echo arg op arg ...
   exit 1
fi

ans=0
operator='+'

while [ "$1" ]
do

case $1 in
'+') ;;
'-') ;;
'/') ;;
'*') ;;
*)
if [ "$1" = "0" ];
    then
        echo "You can't divide by 0"
        exit
    fi;

ans=$(expr $ans "$operator" $1 2>/dev/null)

if [ "$?" = "2" ]
    then
     echo "Only integers"
     exit 1
    fi;

esac
operator=$1
case $operator in
'+'|'-'|'*'|'/') ;;
*) echo Invalid operator: $operator >&2; exit 1;;
esac

shift
done

echo "Answer: $ans";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the string matches an extended regular expression:

```
if [[ "$operator" =~ ^[\-\+/*]$ ]]; then
  printf "Operator %s is valid\n" "$operator"
else
  printf "Invalid operator: '%s'\n" "$operator" >&2
  exit 2
fi
```

(Read `info bash [[`.)